# Replace words in program generated txt files in batch with loop

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Basically the poker client program generates files (txt) as handhistory logs, I would like to have some program that edits the handhistory automaticly, just adding "$" signs in front of numbers then generates new txt files in a new directory so I can have the newly created files analyzed in another software.

below is a sample handhistory log:

```
Full Tilt Poker Game #23461961057: Table .COM Play 463 (deep) - 3000/6000 - No Limit Hold'em - 15:16:29 ET - 2010/08/29  
Seat 2: Player1 (795,425)  
Seat 5: Player2 (1,200,000)  
Player1 posts the small blind of 3,000  
Player2 posts the big blind of 6,000  
The button is in seat #2  
**** HOLE CARDS ****
Dealt to Player1 [Ac 4c]  
Player1 raises to 12,000  
Player2 raises to 687,000  
Player1 raises to 795,425, and is all in  
Player2 folds  
Player2 adds 687,000  
Uncalled bet of 108,425 returned to Player1  
Player1 mucks  
Player1 wins the pot (1,374,000)  
*** SUMMARY ***  
Total pot 1,374,000 | Rake 0  
Seat 2: Player1 (small blind) collected (1,374,000), mucked  
Seat 5: Player2 (big blind) folded before the Flop
```

below is the processed file I'd like:

```
Full Tilt Poker Game #23461961057: Table .COM 463 (deep) - $3000/$6000 - No Limit Hold'em - 15:16:29 ET - 2010/08/29
Seat 2: Player1 ($795,425)
Seat 5: Player2 ($1,200,000)
Player1 posts the small blind of $3,000
Player2 posts the big blind of $6,000
The button is in seat #2
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to Player1 [Ac 4c]
Player1 raises to $12,000
Player2 raises to $687,000
Player1 raises to $795,425, and is all in
Player2 folds
Player2 adds $687,000
Uncalled bet of $108,425 returned to Player1
Player1 mucks
Player1 wins the pot ($1,374,000)
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $1,374,000 | Rake $0
Seat 2: Player1 (small blind) collected ($1,374,000), mucked
Seat 5: Player2 (big blind) folded before the Flop
```

I did some research and came up with AutoHotKey as a result for doing something like this, but I am a newbie when it comes to programming, regular expression is raping my brain as I am typing this. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!Seat )(?<![a-zA-Z#])([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)
```

Replace with $\1

Essentially, what this does is finds all numbers which can be separted by commas which don't start with '#' or a letter or Seat (since I noticed that in the strings "Full Tilt Poker Game #23461961057" and "Seat 2", you didn't add $).  Algorithm is greedy, so that should take into account the fact that the pattern repeats after every comma in a number divided with commas.

If you're using javascript, unfortunately you can't use the look behind.

Comment: Reminds me of the old computer geek joke... "Hey Reggie, look behind you." "What's that?" "Well, it's certainly not JavaScript, hahahha!"

Comment: (The management would like to apologize for that last joke, and reassure you that the author *will* be going back on his medications to prevent further outbursts.)

Comment: Ah well, not really hard to make code look like no existing language now is it?  ~_^